# I was implementing binary search in C and I'm facing this problem which is that its not printing the index number of the element

Tags: c, binary-search, linear-search

**Function For Binary Search**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int binarySearch(int arr[], int size, int element, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        if (arr[mid] == element)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if (element < arr[mid]) //element is on the left side
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1; //element is on the right side
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Main Program Starts Here**

```
int main()
{

    int arr[] = {1, 5, 10, 16, 24, 30, 50, 100};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int element = 10;
    int low = 0;
    int high = size - 1;
    int search = binarySearch(arr, size, element, low, high);
```

so, my problem is that it's not printing this line and in the first place, the compiler is not executing the program. Whenever I try to execute it my pc gets hang

```
    printf("The element %d was found at index %d", element, search);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you declared `mid`?

Comment: how did you calculated `mid `? i

Comment: @silverfox you mean mid = (low + high)/2;
thanks, man! I totally forgot about mid.

Comment: `mid` is used uninitialized invoking Undefined Behavior. Parameter `int size` is unused.

Comment: you can use int `mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);` this formula to avoid overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you forgot to <del>declare</del> initializes/defines `mid`, which will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (after that, anything can happened to your program). You'll also need to recalculate `mid` every time the loop runs.

Also, as @DavidC.Rankin mentioned below, your `sizeArr` parameter is quite unnecessary.

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int binarySearch(int arr[], int element, int low, int high)
{
    int mid; //declare here

    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2; //recalculate here
        if (arr[mid] == element)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (element < arr[mid]) //element is on the left side
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1; //element is on the right side
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 5, 10, 16, 24, 30, 50, 100};
    int sizeArr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int element = 10;
    int low = 0;
    int high = sizeArr - 1;
    int searchResult = binarySearch(arr, sizeArr, element, low, high);
    printf("The element %d was found at index %d", element, searchResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Result :  `The element 10 was found at index 2`

Noted that keywords such as `search` or `size` shouldn't be used as variable names.

Comment: Nitpick: I'd say that the OP's code *declares* `mid`, but never `defines`/`initializes` it. I can see that it exists and that it's an int, but it's initial value is just whatever happened to be on the stack in that spot.

Comment: @Caleb ah my mistake. I was meant to type initializes. Thanks for the clarifier!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no problem, on to it.